# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error when using ember.js(with ember-cli)

Tags: javascript, http, ember.js

Here is my routes in (app/routes/customers.js):

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:3000/odata/customers");
  }
});
```

here is my router.js:

```
export default Router.map(function() {
  this.route('customers', {path: '/'});
});
```

`http://127.0.0.1:3000/odata/customers` is my api, but ember-cli use `http://localhost:4200/`, when I open `http://localhost:4200/`，

in the console, the error message is:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:3000/odata/customers. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.`

I find a article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

so I know what's wrong, but I don't kown how to fix it when use ember.js.

sorry for my poor English, hope thats clear...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not Ember that is the problem. it's the server at port 3000.  If your Ember app is running on a different port, it is basically cross domain and thus the server at port 3000 must be CORS enabled.  Example of this is like this for node js and express: http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html  You need to figure out how to do this for your back end.  But what it comes down to is just basically adding the right headers into the response stream.

Some other example:

http://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html

http://enable-cors.org/server_php.html

Note that if you do want to prevent the Ember server from sending requests to other origins, you can use [Content Security Policies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP).

Comment: This answer seems to be incorrect. Obviously the first page that gets loaded is served by the ember cli app, which is running on port 4200. Whoever loads the first page is responsible for setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. The API server on port 3000 has nothing to do with that. Instead, the ember server should tell the browser it's OK to make ajax calls to localhost:3000, which is done via the header I mentioned.

Comment: Hmm.. isn't that backward? Ember server is the server hosting the current web app at 4200.  That web app is calling another server at port 3000, as per my understanding Access-Control-Allow-Origin is returned back by the server at port 3000... see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS  There is a section where they explained what is going on in the wire...

Comment: The purpose of CORS is to prevent the browser from making ajax calls to servers other than the origin (in our case it's ember on localhost:4200), because they can be potentially malicious. Now imagine the browser will allow ajax calls to any server that is "CORS enabled" as you're suggesting - in this case localhost:3000. Now any malicious server can just "enable CORS" and accept calls. How very secure