# Setting headers in the model hook via ajaxSetup (Ember)

Tags: jquery, ajax, ember.js, getjson

I'm trying to set the headers before making my call and it's not working.

```
model: function() {
        debugger;

        Ember.$.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader(
                    'Authorization', 'bearer 123456'
                )
        }});

        return Ember.$.getJSON('http://addresss/api/locations').then(function(e) {
            debugger;
            console.log(e);
        });
    }
```

This keeps giving me the following error message:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

If I use Postman and set my header it works fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access-Control-Allow-Origin error when using ember.js(with ember-cli)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147362/access-control-allow-origin-error-when-using-ember-jswith-ember-cli)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes setting xhr field  - `withCredentials` - to `true` helps to get past such error. Please try:

```
Ember.$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'bearer 123456');
    }
});
```

Comment: Is `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header present in `http://addresss/api/locations` response? If not you can't make cross domain request without adding this header first on server side.

Comment: Please check in developer tools whether getJSON request has your custom header attached.

Comment: I figured it out. I had a nested call (different domain) that needed the header set but because I was setting it before making my first call it was throwing an error. Once I moved the setRequestHeader logic inside the first getJSON call everything worked.